# Auto select new rows in Grafana (InfluxDB)

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a measurement in InfluxDB that is named `Tasks` and look like this:

```
recordname,failure,waiting,timestamp
```

And in Grafana I have two panels, one for waiting and one for failure. Example:

```
SELECT "failure" 
FROM "Tasks" 
WHERE 
  ("recordname" = 'Random_record_name') 
  AND time >= now() - 24h 
GROUP BY "recordname";
```

The data only uploads in Influx if there is a task that fails or is waiting. Therefore I cannot add all the queries for each recordname until they happen. Is there a way to format the query to select all failures for all recordnames so I don't have to manually add them?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve. Query result examples will be more usefull. But why you are filtering `"recordname" = 'Random_record_name'` for particular recordname, when you have grouping `GROUP BY "recordname"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to remove the filter on the recordname:

```
SELECT "failure" 
FROM "Tasks" 
WHERE 
  time >= now() - 24h 
GROUP BY "recordname";
```

This will return a series for each recordname in your database.

Since you mention Grafana in your question I will add (as a suggestion) to set the alias of the query to `$tag_recordname`. This way your series will be named according to recordname (the default is a bit less readable).